# where is rake task acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations defined?

Tags: ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

In the document of gem acts-as-taggable-on, there is one step about installing migrations after gem installation. (https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#post-installation)

```
# For the latest versions :
rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations
rake db:migrate
```

I couldn't find the definition of this rake task `acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations`. Could any one give any information about this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`install:migrations` is inherited from `Rails::Engine`
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#engine-setup

In the repo: this happens in: `/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/engine.rb` and the files in `db/migrate`